# Converting JS to Typescript Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

when I try to convert this js to typescript I am getting some errors.
The first one is for the **event**

It says: Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type

I could put any type on the event, but would like to know the right data type to use instead of a generic one.

The other one is for the following line:

```
 if (!ref.current?.contains(event.target)) {
```

error:

```
   Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'never'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (event) => {
      if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        if (!ref.current?.contains(event.target)) {
          if (!open) return;
          setOpen(false);
        }
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  }, [open, ref]);
```

Comment: To answer the part about the ref we'll need to see the code that creates `ref`, and also what type of element you pass it into.

Comment: thank you. It says: const ref: React.MutableRefObject<null>

Comment: And what type of element do you pass it into? Eg, if you do `<div ref={ref}>` then the answer to my question is "div".

Comment: <Context.Provider value={{ open, ref, toggle }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>

Comment: Ok... and where does it go from there? I can't tell you what type it should be if i don't know what dom element you're passing it into.

Comment: It's imported and returned into here (as the dashboard provider):

export default function DashboardLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <DashboardProvider>

Comment: `event` should be type `MouseEvent`. I give up on the `ref`.

Answer (score 2):

`const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);`

use HTMLDivElement type it contains contains (haha).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const ref = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

contains(e.target as HTMLDivElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing it into a use effect is not needed. You can have this within the component itself and manage the removal of the event on the toggle. See below.

```
const [ showDropdown, setShowDropdown ] = useState(false)
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

function toggleDropdown() {
    setShowDropdown(!showDropdown);

    document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
}
const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as HTMLDivElement)) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        
        toggleDropdown()
    }
};

document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);


return (
    <div className='relative'>
        <button onClick={toggleDropdown}> 
          This is meant to be clicked by the user
        </button>
        { showDropdown ?
            <div ref={ref}>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <button type="button">
                            Update
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="button">
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            : null
        }
    </div>
)
```

Note - The css is not provided and the icons. The use case I found, is when you click on an icon you want a dropdown to appear. The logic above does that logic to render.

Documentation to follow is below to keep aligned with the intentions on useEffect.
https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects
https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect